# React Native change state leads to mobx-state-tree exception

Tags: react-native, setstate, mobx-state-tree

I have a problem with changing the value in my state. I have

```
state = {
    ......,
    tags: []
}
```

and these tags are filled like:

```
tags: this.props.userStore.details.tags
```

tags are a list of dictionaries:

```
tags = [{'name': tag1, 'userSelect': true}, {'name': tag2, 'userSelect': false}]
```

I display them all in the checkbox:

```
renderTagCheckbox() {
    return this.state.tags.map((item, key) => {
      return(
        <TouchableOpacity key={key} style={{flexDirection: "row", marginTop: 5, justifyContent: "center"}}>
          <CheckBox
            isChecked={item.userSelect}
            onClick={() => this.changeCheckboxValue(item)}
          />
          <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    })
  }
```

in my `changCheckboxValue()` I have:

```
  changeCheckboxValue(item) {
    //this.refersSubscriptions.forEach(s => s.remove())
    let currentTags = this.state.tags
    currentTags.forEach(tag => {
      if (tag===item) {
        tag.userSelect = !tag.userSelect
      }
    })
  }
```

and this way I was thinking I could setState with `currentTags` where the value will be change, but I get an error:

`[mobx-state-tree]Cannot modify 'tags@/userStore/details/tags/0', the object is protected and can only be modified by using an action.`

Could somebody give me any tips on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you share the code snippet that produces the error?

Comment: @novonimo the problem is with `changeCheckboxValue` - when I try to `tag.userSelect = !tag.userSelect` I got error

Comment: are you using 'useState' hook to create your state? 
are you using class component or functional component?

Comment: @novonimo I'm using class component without useState

Comment: are your tags stored in a global store?

Comment: tags are injected via userStore to my class (using mobx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `mobx-state-tree` document:

> By default, nodes can only be modified by one of their actions, or by actions higher up in the tree.

You put your `tags` in a global state which is an immutable object. so avoid changing your global state via inline codes in your component.

you can define propper `actions` and dispatch them for those changes.

for more information about the actions in `mobx-state-tree` look at the [documentation](https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/concepts/actions).